# Deleting Salesforce developer account

Tags: org

I need to delete salesforce developer account.Can I do this? If yes, how?

Comment: According to the [Master Subscription Agreement](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_Developer_MSA.pdf) for developer organizations (which is what you agree to when you sign up for one), "10.3. Termination. You may terminate Basic Developer Service User Subscriptions without cause at any time upon written notice to Us." I'm not sure what would constitute written notice, though, since the document does not specify an address for this specific purpose. (I'm assuming you mean a developer organization, as opposed to an Account record in your org.)

Comment: @Carolyn This is a great post, you should post it as an answer, you'll get my vote

Comment: @DanielBlackhall posted.

Answer (score 10):

Accounts cannot be deleted from Salesforce, just inactivated. This may seem odd, but it helps provide data consistency and it is a common practice to "inactivate" data rather than delete it.

Comment: can we log a case for this? so that our account will get deleted

Comment: I doubt they would let you log a case; the system does not allow for deleting accounts by design but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Master Subscription Agreement](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_Developer_MSA.pdf) for developer organizations (which is what you agree to when you sign up for one),

> 10.3. Termination. You may terminate Basic Developer Service User
>   Subscriptions without cause at any time upon written notice to Us.

I'm not sure what would constitute written notice, though, since the document does not specify an address for this specific purpose.

(I'm assuming you mean a developer organization, as opposed to an Account record in your org.)

(Reposted from comment as suggested.)

Comment: yes i mean developer organization.

Answer (score 4):

As @Carolyn commented to the question - I think the question is whether Developer Orgs can be deleted rather than user accounts.

The answer is the same however, developer orgs are not generally deletable.

You cannot deactivate all users in an org, and you cannot deactivate the user you are logged in as.

I would suggest:

- Purge any data you have created (or configuration changes you have made) which you would not want anyone to see, this includes company info
- Undo any configuration you have made in the org which may cause emails to be sent to you (for example Chatter emails)
- Edit the user and deselect the email news options

---

Instead of signing up for a developer org, you can sign up for trial orgs which expire after a set period, this is better for general evaluation of Salesforce features than a developer org.

Answer (score 4):

You can now deactivate developer edition orgs from Setup => Custom Settings -> Company Information. There is a Deactivate Org button. It walks you through a bunch of confirmation screens. It also gives you 30 days to change your mind (60 if you open a ticket).